# Xcode error: Missing required module 'Firebase'

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoapods, static-libraries

**The problem:**

I have a dynamic framework, which uses `Firebase` added by cocoapods. And I also have the App, which uses this dynamic framework. But when I try to build the project I got error `Missing required module Firebase`.

**I tried the following:**

- remove derived data + clean
- re-install pods
- add 'Import paths' to the build settings (in this case I got error 'Library not loaded' in runtime)

**My podfile:**

```
target 'Project' do    
  ...
end
target 'Framework' do    
  pod 'Firebase/Core'
  pod 'Firebase/Auth'
end
```

The `Framework` is added to `Embedded binaries` and `Linked Frameworks and Libraries`.

Comment: Do you see the framework flag in 'Other Linker Flags'?

Comment: @MarmikShah No, I don't

Comment: if you have a test target please add that to pod file along with same pods which is used on other target as well.

Comment: Hello, anything new on that?

Comment: Hello, did you solve it ?

Comment: anything? @TungVuDuc

Answer (score 72):

For anyone still having this issue, doing this solved it for me. 
Add this to your test target build settings.

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"
```

[Full discussion can be found on firebase GitHub issues.](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/16)

you can find HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Test Target > Build Settings > Search Paths > Header Search paths.

Just incase you cant find HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS in Build Settings, click the ALL button to show all settings.

Comment: This worked for me, thank you.
I believe it should be the accepted answer.

Comment: The OP did not ask about unit test at all.

Comment: That worked! Thanks

Answer (score 37):

Add the following to your test target:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = "${PODS_ROOT}/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources"
```

That’s in *test target > Build Settings > Header Search Paths*.

Comment: The OP did not ask about unit test.

Comment: Even when he didn’t mention anything about tests, having one is the most likely cause for this error.

Answer (score 5):

After adding test target, running:

```
pod install
```

and add to:

```
HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited)
```

fixed for me.

On Framework Search Path pod put all pod projects path automatically.

Of course, to podfile added this after last pod name:

```
target 'TestTargetName' do
  inherit! :search_paths
end
```

Comment: I needed to add "${SRCROOT}/Pods/Firebase/CoreOnly/Sources" to this solution.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing did help to me until

```
target 'TestTargetName' do
  
    pod 'Firebase/Storage'
  
end
```

I'm not sure what firebase does so I can't run tests (tests do not depend on firebase at all)