# Swift Compiler Error: Missing required modules;

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods

I want to create custom pod which is depends on other pod. I have podspec file

```
 ...
 s.source_files = "ios/**/*.{h,c,m,swift}"
 s.requires_arc = true

 s.dependency "UserSDK"
```

UserSDK is pod which i want to use in my custom module. It has own dependencies like  `FirebaseCore`, `FirebaseMessaging` [UserSDK podspec](https://github.com/UserEngage/iOS-SDK/blob/master/UserSDK.podspec)

In my CustomModule.swift file has

```
import Foundation
import UserSDK
```

To use custom library include it via pod file;

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'MyTarget' do

pod 'FBLazyVector', :path => "../modules/react-native/Libraries/FBLazyVector"
pod 'FBReactNativeSpec', :path => "../modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec"
pod 'RCTRequired', :path => "../modules/react-native/Libraries/RCTRequired"
pod 'RCTTypeSafety', :path => "../modules/react-native/Libraries/TypeSafety"
pod 'React', :path => '../modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-Core', :path => '../modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-CoreModules', :path => '../modules/react-native/React/CoreModules'
pod 'React-Core/DevSupport', :path => '../modules/react-native/'
pod 'React-RCTActionSheet', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/ActionSheetIOS'
pod 'React-RCTAnimation', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/NativeAnimation'
pod 'React-RCTBlob', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Blob'
pod 'React-RCTImage', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Image'
pod 'React-RCTLinking', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/LinkingIOS'
pod 'React-RCTNetwork', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Network'
pod 'React-RCTSettings', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Settings'
pod 'React-RCTText', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Text'
pod 'React-RCTVibration', :path => '../modules/react-native/Libraries/Vibration'
pod 'React-Core/RCTWebSocket', :path => '../modules/react-native/'

pod 'CustomModule', :path => "../CustomModule"

end
```

error[image]

If I add `use_frameworks!` to target in podfile it works, but then other dependencies do not work

Comment: Show how you're embedding your custom pod into your app. Messing around with framework search path should not be necessary. Also, `requires_src` is probably a typo of `requires_arc` , and `dependency`  is spelled with two `n`s.

Comment: Did you tried to reinstall the UserSDK pod? It seems be missing ${PODS_ROOT}/Google/Headers...  Try to add that to headers path

Comment: @Carla Camargo yes i tried, also cant find Google in pods, but there are FirebaseCore, FireabaseInstanceID and FirebaseMessaging, Adding it to headers path doesnt work

Comment: @Gereon updated my question., also removed path from framework searh path. It seems its not necessary like you said

Comment: Please show your full list of pods, or ideally, your complete Podfile

Comment: @Gereon update my question. I searched a lot and it seems i need to add module map to my library to make available firebase. not sure [.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757417/swift-app-missing-required-module-when-importing-framework-that-imports-stati](.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31757417/swift-app-missing-required-module-when-importing-framework-that-imports-stati)

Comment: What's not working with `use_frameworks!`?

Comment: Did you create UserSDK that have FirebaseCore, Firebase  frameworks inside ?

Answer (score 3):

In the `podspec` file , couple fields are missing **I guess** like

- `Deployment_Target`
- `Source Files`

  Use `inherit! :search_paths` in `Podfile` before `end`.

Refer : https://ronakshah.org/How-To-Make-A-Cocoapod-With-Dependencies

and for your specific error add following in `podfile`

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
```

OR refer :
[Xcode error: Missing required module 'Firebase'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53700747/12456741)

[Swift app: “Missing required module” when importing framework that imports static library](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31757417/12456741)